# How to handle several ports of my own GitHub project?

Tags: github

This question is similar to [Porting a Github repo to another language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9115223/porting-a-github-repo-to-another-language) but there is a distinction, so please do not mark as duplicate.

If I'm writing software, say a library, and maintaining a GitHub repo, how should I handle porting my own code to different languages?

For example, if I write a library in nodejs and I also port that to PHP, python and Go, what would be the best way to handle this?

Would it be wise to do this all in a single repo, where each port would get its own branch? Or should I fork the original version and just name the fork "mylib-php," "mylib-py," etc. ?

Comment: In my opinion, since you will never merge branches to main branch, there is no point to handle it in a single repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several repos are preferable, as it would establish a clear separation not only in code history (that wouldn't be merged together), but also in:

- forks (one go contributor isn't interested in php code)
- PR (Pull Requests)
- issues

You can then have a consistent policy across repos, when for instance master represents the latest stable dev. Each cloned repo represents a working code (as opposed to one repo with multiple branch, where you need to seek and find the right branch after cloning)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! One last thing @VonC, do you think the ported version should be forked from the original, for the purpose of maintaining a sibling-like link between the versions? Or would a straight up new repo be preferable with maybe a "SISTER-PROJECTS.md" file? I'm new to OSS, so pardon the questions!

Comment: @WhiskeyTangoFoxtrot no fork necessary, unless you intend to backport (merge back) some commit through pull requests. Since the repos are for different languages, that seems unlikely.